# Bootstrap Overflow

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I design a new web site. I use bootstrap but ı hava a problem.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2 red-border">
    asdasdlknadlamaslfknasjşklfnsadjşlkfnbasdşjlfksnadbfjşa 
  </div>
</div>

.red-border{
   text-align: center;
   margin-top: 50px;
   border: solid 2px red;
   height: 250px;
   margin-left: 20px;
}
```

When I wrote this code, ı see that.

[image]

Thank you everyone.

Comment: Try having spaces in between words. The browser thinks that the text you put in is one word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not totally sure what result you are looking for but it looks like the column size you set in bootstrap `col-md-2` is too small for your content. You could increase the size of it or handle the overflowing content in different ways. The following code will hide overflow:

```
.red-border{
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border: solid 2px red;
  height: 250px;
  margin-left: 20px;

  // ADDED STYLE
  overflow: hidden;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is "wrap" the text. just add this to your `.red-border style`:

`word-wrap: break-word;`